# MSSQL 2019 A connection was successfully established with the server

Tags: sql-server

I use Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU7) (KB4570012) - 15.0.4063.15 (X64) Aug 15 2020 10:48:11 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS)

I develop with .net core 3.1.8 web api using Kestrel :

problem/error message: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Success)

What can be the problem?

my config file:

```
     [sqlagent]
     enabled = false

     [EULA]
     accepteula = Y

     [coredump]
     captureminiandfull = true
     coredumptype = full

     [network]
     forceencryption = 0
     ipaddress = xx.xx.xx.xxx
```

my connection string:

`$"Server={ServerName};Database={DBName};User Id={UserName};Password={Password};Max Pool Size=50000;Pooling=True;"`

Comment: Did you modify the tlsciphers list? It doesn't look like the default list at [Configure SQL Server on Linux with the mssql-conf tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf#mssql-conf-format).

Comment: Please edit your question to include your connection string. For security reasons don't use your real server name/IP address, username and password, but try not to change the format you have in code/configuration.

Comment: I edit mssql config file, don't need me tls. tls removed config file.

`[sqlagent]
enabled = false

[EULA]
accepteula = Y

[coredump]
captureminiandfull = true
coredumptype = full

[network]
forceencryption = 0
ipaddress = xx.xx.xx.xxx`

my connetion string:

`$"Server={ServerName};Database={DBName};User Id={UserName};Password={Password};Max Pool Size=50000;Pooling=True;"`